# Iterate QTreeView Rows

Tags: python

How would i modify the function below to properly iterate through just the rows in my QTreeview and not each row and each column?
While iterating through each row, I want to get the UserRole and DisplayRole data of the second column.

[image]

I'm close on the iteration part, but im not sure how to access UserRole and Display Role of the second column.

```
import sys, random
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore


class Browser(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Browser, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 400)

        self.uiItems = QtGui.QTreeView()
        self.uiItems.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.uiItems.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.uiItems.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.uiItems.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.proxyModel = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel())
        self.proxyModel.setDynamicSortFilter(True)
        self.uiItems.setModel(self.proxyModel)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Print')

        grid = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.uiItems)
        grid.addWidget(self.button)

        self.populate()
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.printData)


    def populate(self):
        items = ['Cookie','Hummus','Spaghetti','Candy','Chocolate']
        subitems = ['Sweet','Caramel','Sucker','Apple']

        model = self.proxyModel.sourceModel()
        model.clear()
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Name', 'Count'])

        for item in items:
            count = random.randint(0,3)
            col1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(item)
            # col2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(count))

            # subitems:
            for i in range(count):
                child1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(subitems[random.randint(0,3)])
                child2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(random.randint(0,20)))
                col1.appendRow([child1, child2])

            model.appendRow([col1])

        self.uiItems.expandAll()
        self.uiItems.header().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)


    def iterItems(self, root):
        if root is not None:
            stack = [root]
            while stack:
                parent = stack.pop(0)
                for row in range(parent.rowCount()):
                    for column in range(parent.columnCount()):
                        child = parent.child(row, column)
                        yield child
                        if child and child.hasChildren():
                            stack.append(child)


    def printData(self):
        for x in self.iterItems(self.proxyModel.sourceModel().invisibleRootItem()):
            print x


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Browser()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Anyone have an ideas?

Comment: It would be good to mention your PyQt version here. This doesn't work with PyQt5 (nor do either of the current two answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def iterItems(self, root):
    if root is not None:
        for row in range(root.rowCount()):
            row_item = root.child(row, 0)
            if row_item.hasChildren():
                for childIndex in range(row_item.rowCount()):
                    # Take second column from "child"-row
                    child = row_item.child(childIndex, 1)
                    yield child



def printData(self):
    for x in self.iterItems(self.proxyModel.sourceModel().invisibleRootItem()):
        print x.data(role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole), x.data(role=QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'QTreeView' object has no attribute 'proxyModel' ...??

Answer (score 1):

If it works for you, a [QTreeWidgetItemIterator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitemiterator.html) might be much easier:

```py
def iterTreeItems(tree)
  iterator = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItemIterator(tree)
  item: QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem = iterator.value()
  while item is not None:
    yield item
    iterator += 1
    item = iterator.value()
```

Comment: QTreeWidgetItemIterator(QTreeWidgetItem, flags: QTreeWidgetItemIterator.IteratorFlags = QTreeWidgetItemIterator.All): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QTreeView' ... ??

Comment: What version of Qt are you using? If that's not the issue, it might require a widget intsead of a view (but I'm not sure, I just know I used this with a TreeWidget instread of a view)

Comment: v 5.15. Yes, that's right... but the question was about `QTreeView`. The same goes for the other question (which was puzzlingly accepted): I'm mystified because I can't seem to find `proxyModel` even for `QTreeWidget`, in 5.15 docs at least.